# $rank(A) > rank(B) $ then $rank(f(A)) \geq rank(f(B)) $

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

> Find the polynomial functions $f$  with  real coefficients such that for every $ A, B \in M_4( \mathbb{R})$ with $\mbox{rank}(A) > \mbox{rank}(B) $ we have that $\mbox{rank}(f(A)) \geq \mbox{rank}(f(B)) $.

---

How to start? I tried with some examples but doesn't work.

Comment: Which examples did you try? What is the context? What can you use?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde  With one nonzero element on the diagonal?

Comment: For *every* matrix $A$ and $B$, not only for one matrix. Which $f$ did you try?

Comment: My guess at a method:  First find the polynomials $f$ that work for diagonal matrices $A,B$.  Then investigate these polynomials for non-trivial Jordan blocks to deal with the general case.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde  must be used Jordan form?